# SQL full outer join or Union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different tables. One is a `Article` table and another is `Gallery` table. The gallery contains multiple images , so there is another table named `images` (which is not shown here). The images in the `images` table link to gallery table with a foreign key `gallery_id`.

Now what I am trying to achieve is, in the home page, I need the combined result of both the articles and galleries. If its a article, the thumbnail of the article is displayed and if its a gallery, the last image from the gallery is displayed.

```
|Article    | 
|-----------|
|id         |
|category_id|
|title      |
|slug       |
|filename   |
|body       |
|created    |
|modified   |
```

---

```
|Gallery|
|-----------|
|id         |
|category_id|
|title      |
|slug       |
|body       |
|created    |
|modified   |
```

I am using a very complex `UNION` query to achieve it. But how can I sort the results. Is it possible to use a `ORDER BY` clause. Can the result be achieved with `OUTER JOIN` ?

Comment: You want SELECT ... FROM (-- union query --) x ORDER BY x.col - if I was you I would make a view of the union query for easy use elsewhere which would make the query a lot less unsightly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `outer join` does not apply here because you want your results to be in one column. Joins make data in two columns, unions make data into one column.

to do a sort you can do something like this

```
Select  id         
    , category_id
    , title      
    , slug       
    , filename   
    , body       
    , created    
    , modified
From (  
    Select id         
        , category_id
        , title      
        , slug       
        , filename   
        , body       
        , created    
        , modified 
    From Article 
    Union All Select id         
        , category_id
        , title      
        , slug       
        , body       
        , created    
        , modified 
    From Gallery
) AllCombined
Order by AllCombined.title
```